# flex 4.5/Air 's android app

Tags: android, air, flex4.5

I am thinking of using Flex4/Air for developing an Android app. I want the app to have hover to play like ability. I mean if a video thumbnail is selected from alist of videos but not clicked it should play a 5 second clip just like in bing.com/videos. I am assuming this is the closest we come to "hover" in Android devices - please correct me if ths is not the case.

Does Flex4/Air have this capability? Otherwise can we implement hover-to-play ability on Android devices?

Appreciate any help/pointers.

Comment: I don't think many people use the 4 way nav to select items (if that's what you meant) even if they have it on their phones, on the touchscreen you should avoid designing around the hover pattern.

Comment: Careful not to confuse Flash Builder 4.5 and the Flex 4. SDK.  Flash Builder is the IDE.  You are interested in the capabilities of the SDK.

Comment: Yes Flex 4.5 SDK comes with Flash Builder 4.5

Comment: Agreed, the Flex 4.5 comes with Flash Builder.  But you asked "Does Flash Builder 4.5 have this capability".  They are separate products.  You can build Flex-based Android apps without Flash Builder.  Your question is about the SDK, not Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does Flash Builder 4.5 have this capability?  No! I think you meant to ask does Flex 4.5 have this capability, but the question would be best stated: "does AIR for Android have this capability?  If so, how can I access it in Flex?"

When developing code for mobile devices, I would take great care when implementing functionality based on a "hover" approach.  However, you can take a look at these touch events:

1. [TOUCH_OVER](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#TOUCH_OVER)
2. [TOUCH_ROLL_OVER](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#TOUCH_ROLL_OVER)

I thought a Long Press / Long Touch event may be what you need, but I couldn't find any documented one supported by AIR's touch API.